# Get childnode from element

Tags: javascript, css

I have the following code:

```
<div class="className" id="div-1" onClick="selPic(this.id);">
   <span>some text</span>
</div>
<div class="className" id="div-2" onClick="selPic(this.id);">
   <span>some text</span>
</div>
<div class="className" id="div-3" onClick="selPic(this.id);">
   <span>some text</span>
</div>
```

I'd like to give the span of the clicked element some styling but I'd prefer to use the parent element's id for reference rather than giving each span an id as well.

I have tried this, but it doesn't work:

```
function selPic(id) {
    document.getElementById(id).childNone[0].style.opacity = "1";
}
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Access to the element 1 of childNodes (not childNode) array to modify the span opacity:

```
document.getElementById(id).childNodes[1].style.opacity = "1";
```

Comment: Yes, this worked! Apart from childNode that should be childNodes I also had the number wrong (should be [1] not [0]). Thanks!

Comment: I'm glad to have helped you. So please mark my answer as the valid one :) .

Comment: This approach only works by accident. You'll never know for sure if the index should be 0 or 1 because there may be an invisible child node before the span. See my answer for a more robust solution.

Answer (score 2):

Just correct the typos in your code:

```
function selPic(id) {
    document.getElementById(id).childNodes[0].style.opacity = "1";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Replace `childNone` with `childNodes`.

```
function selPic(id) {
    document.getElementById(id).childNodes[0].style.opacity = "1";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It should be **childNodes** not childNode:

```
function selPic(id) {
    document.getElementById(id).childNodes[0].style.opacity = "1";
}
```

---

Also, habituate to use return the function:

```
function selPic(id) {
   var ss = document.getElementById(id).childNodes[0].style.opacity = "1";
   return ss;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have a bit of error code

```
function selPic(id) {
document.getElementById(id).childNodes[0].style.opacity = "1";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your idea of selecting a child node by index number will not work in general. That's because you cannot know for sure what number the span element will have. Depending on how you built the list, there may be invisible child nodes, such as whitespace text nodes, before the span that interests you. That's why you were surprised to find that you had to use index value 1 rather than 0.

A more robust approach is to call `getElementsByTagName('span')` on the parent element to retrieve all the spans inside it. Then get the first item in the returned array.

In addition, I suggest that the argument to the function should be the element you want to highlight and not just the ID of the element. If you follow my suggestion, your HTML would look like this:

```
<div class="className" id="div-1" onClick="selectPicture(this);">
   <span>some text</span>
</div>
<div class="className" id="div-2" onClick="selectPicture(this);">
   <span>some text</span>
</div>
<div class="className" id="div-3" onClick="selectPicture(this);">
   <span>some text</span>
</div>
```

And the function would look like this:

```
function selectPicture(container) {
    container.getElementsByTagName('span')[0].style.opacity = 1;
}
```

It would be even better to implement the style change by modifying the `className` of the span and writing appropriate CSS, but I'll leave those considerations up to you.